# The closure of a connected is connected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness

Let $A$ be connected. Assume $Cl(A)$ is not, then they exist not empty open sets $U,V$ s.t $Cl(A)=U\cup V$ and $U \cap V = \varnothing$

because $A$ is connected $A\subseteq U$ or $A\subseteq V$ without loss of generality assume $A\subseteq U$

$\Rightarrow Cl(A)\supseteq  A\cup V$ , $\Rightarrow Cl(A)\setminus A \supseteq V $,  but from the hypothesis $V=Cl(A)\setminus U \Rightarrow A\supseteq U$
So $U=A$

and we have  $Cl(A)=A\cup V \Rightarrow$ $Cl(A)=Cl(A)\cup Cl(V) $, $\: V= \varnothing$

I think this is a different proof, is it correct ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131509/discussion-on-question-by-lupus-nox-the-closure-of-a-connected-is-connected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your proof is not correct. To see where it fails, let us consider a connected subset $A$ of a topological space $X$. At the moment it is irrelevant whether or not $X = \operatorname{cl}A$. Your proof works a s follows:

Assume $X$ is not connected, then there exist nonempty open sets $U,V \subset X$ such that $X=U\cup V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

Because $A$ is connected $A\subseteq U$ or $A\subseteq V$, without loss of generality assume $A\subseteq U$.

You correctly state

1. $X \supseteq  A\cup V$ (this is trivial)
2. $X\setminus A \supseteq V$ (follows from $A\subseteq U$)
3. $V=X\setminus U$ (this is trivial)

But then you say that $A\supseteq U$ (which would imply $U=A$). This cannot be concluded from the above facts: To establish these facts, you did nowhere use that $X = \operatorname{cl}A$. And now look at $X = (0,2) \cup (2,3) \subset \mathbb R$. Take $A = (0,1)$, $U  = (0,2)$, $V = (2,3)$.

What you are doing is in fact too complicated. After assuming w.l.o.g that $A \subseteq U$, you know that $A \subseteq X \setminus V$. The latter set is closed, thus $\operatorname{cl}A \subseteq X \setminus V \subsetneqq X$. Now you can consider the case that $X = \operatorname{cl}A$. You get $\operatorname{cl}A \subsetneqq \operatorname{cl}A $, a contradiction.